# Data correction techniques for shuttlecock prediction/detection

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, artificial-intelligence, kalman-filter

Thanks in advance for taking the time out to help me with this question, I have been tackling this issue for a while now.

So here's my issue:
I have been working on a project using Python OpenCV to detect and predict the path of a shuttlecock using a ZED Camera (Stereo Cameras) Link:https://www.stereolabs.com/zed/

The techniques I am currently using is color detection and motion detection for the same. While most of the data I get is pretty accurate, some of the data points seem to be going way out of bounds.

Below is a sample of the data points and a graph which shows the data points being plotted.

Can someone help me with a way to correct the points which seem to be going away from the detected values?

I am using Extended Kalman filter for trajectory prediction, after referring to some research papers related to the same.

Can someone please let me know if the path chosen by me is on the right track or if I am missing something?

I also did read somewhere about using AI blocks but I'm not sure what I would be doing with them, any pointers on that would be a good too. :-)

Picture of the 3D Graph(detected points):[Detected Points](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aPEBW.jpg)

Shuttlecock Trajectory(Orange blurred line):[How should be the actual path look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNjJD.jpg)

Data  [X,Y,Z - coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjFta.jpg)

Comment: Yeah, Kalman filter should do the trick here. You will need to use some approximation to reach you final goal, because it does not require full trajectory.

Comment: Please provide an example of your code, your data (in text form). Outer links should be used only as complementary info.